# How to save only the rows with a specific numpy array / matrix shape in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

Say I have a dataframe `df`, and a column `'Array'` that contains bunch of numpy arrays. Now I want to save only the rows with the array shape that most commonly existed in this column, and drop the other rows. I want to input these arrays as features to do some machine learning stuff, so I need to ensure they are all in a same shape. Below is my script, but it doesn't work. I hope the answer should also works when the features are matrices.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
lst = [i.shape for i in df['Array']]
most_common = max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
df = df[df['Array'].shape==most_common]
```

Basically I want to convert atomic structures into numerical features like numpy arrays or matrices. I'm using a method called Coulomb Matrix to achieve this. In case you want to try yourselves, this is my whole script:

```
import pandas as pd
from ase.db import connect
from ase import Atoms
from ase.io import read
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as linalg

def eig_data(atoms):
    init_R = atoms.positions
    init_Z = atoms.numbers
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    z_list = []
    M_list = []
    M_tmp = []
    M_matrix = []
    for x,y,z in init_R:
        x_list.append(x)
        y_list.append(y)
        z_list.append(z)
    order=0
    for xl,yl,zl,Z in zip(x_list,y_list,z_list,init_Z):
        M_list.append((order,xl,yl,zl,Z))
        order+=1
    for order,x,y,z,charge in M_list:
        r = np.array((x,y,z))
        M_tmp = []
        for oorder,ox,oy,oz,ocharge in M_list:
            if oorder == order:
                IJ = 0.5*ocharge**2.4
                M_tmp.append(IJ)
            else:
                otr = np.array((ox,oy,oz))
                dist = np.linalg.norm(r-otr)
                InJ = (charge*ocharge)/dist
                M_tmp.append(InJ)
        M_matrix.append(M_tmp)
    M = np.array(M_matrix)
    w,v = np.linalg.eig(M)
    w_sort = np.sort(w)[::-1]
#    print(np.amax(w_sort))
    return w_sort

res = connect('c2db.db')
df = []
for row in res.select():
    atoms = row.toatoms()
    i = row.id
    c = eig_data(atoms)
    f = row.formula
    E = row.energy
    g = row.gap
    w = row.workfunction
    df.append({'id': i, 'c_matrix':c, 'formula':f, 'energy': E, 'band_gap':g, 'work_function':w})
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

lst = [i.shape for i in df['c_matrix']]
most_common = max(set(lst), key=lst.count)
df = df[df['c_matrix'].shape==most_common]
```

The database can be downloaded here: [c2db_database](https://cmr.fysik.dtu.dk/c2db/c2db.html)

Comment: Can you show the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to create a filter in this way for your dataframe

```
filter = [i.shape == most_common for i in df['c_matrix']]
df = df[filter]
```

Or simply

```
df = df[[i.shape == most_common for i in df['c_matrix']]]
```